# Allow libertine apps full access to sd card on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, m10

I would like to use libertine apps to read epub and cbz files on my SD Card. How can I enable access for these apps so that they can navigate to the proper folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your SD card into your libertine-container by creating a directory (e.g. called 'mount') into the ~/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/CONTAINERID/ and execute the command: sudo mount -B /media/phablet/YOURSDCARD/ ~/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/CONTAINERID/mount/ and you have access to your SD card in libertine from the container's home directory. Of course you can bind your SD card anywhere else in you libertine-container :)